# How can I add a build step to leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

So I've got an application built using Foundation and Ring, and I want to be able to compile my custom Foundation CSS whenever I run `lein ring server` or the like. Specifically, I'd like to be able to add a step the runs `compass compile [path]`. What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, Leiningen Hooks are the proper and idiomatic way to do so:  [Hooks](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PLUGINS.md#hooks).

> You can modify the behaviour of built-in tasks to a degree using hooks. Hook functionality is provided by the Robert Hooke library, which is included with Leiningen.

Comment: Does the hook block the completion of the build? In other words, is the build not considered complete until all hooks have executed?

Comment: Meanwhile in the distant future, hooks have been deprecated but the documentation doesn't mention any alternative. I'm assuming the sensible way to proceed is to wrap the 'lein' call as a custom step in some other build process (e.g. npm, maven)